# How to stop connection points from changing when shapes moved or resized?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

In Visio 2013, often times when moving shapes or resizing them the connection points change. This is one of the many baffling behaviors of this program to me.

Demo video: http://screencast.com/t/cSo6pd85H

How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your text label "N" that is pushing the connector away. Just move the label "N" a bit to the right, or configure it to not interfere with connectors (Behavior -> Placement -> Do not layout and route around). Or better yet, just remove it and provide "N" label on the connector itself (select the connector and type "N"). You will be able to position the label with a handle.

Video:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ellf2taukmwqwu/2015-03-10_21-25-47.MP4?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

The connection points are part of the shape. When the shape gets moved the connection points will move as well.

Comment: The connection points should move with the shape, but if you watch the video what you'll see is that the connection point isn't moved for the line, it's changed to a completely different connection point on the shape (from the bottom to the side).

Comment: Sorry, the video is nothing like clear enough to show that to me.

Comment: So, it's not the connection points that are moving, it's the connector moving to a different glue point on the shape. That is very different. That is dynamic glue i.e. the connector has been connected to the centre of the shape, when the shape gets moved or resized the connector moves to a more suitable connection point. Try attaching the connector to the edge of the shape.

Answer (score 0):

This is often a snap and glue connection problem in Visio's floor layouts or architectural drawings; for example, where you want to place a door shape into a wall. After choosing the door shape from the Shapes stencils, and positioning it to the correct wall orientation--the door shape jumps, rotates, and snaps to a nearby shape and cannot be correctly re-placed or reoriented!

To correct this behavior, first place the wall shape into the desired location. Then you must select from the Shapes stencil the "OPENING" shape. The opening shape will rotate and place easily into the wall. Then select from the Shape stencil the "DOOR" shape. The door's geometry has a connection point in the middle of its entry area that will automatically snap onto the opening's connection point located in the middle of its geometry. Now you can relocate the door to your desired placement in the wall from its attachment within the "OPENING" shape, by using Visio's normal shape resizing and rotating features of the door shape.

I guess this makes sense because a wall would first need an opening to place something like a door or window into it. I made the mistake of thinking the shape would contain the opening and not need an additional step to place it.